# Flask app "Restarting with stat"

Tags: python, flask

I've built a few Flask apps, but on my latest project I noticed something a little strange in development mode.  The second line of the usual message in the terminal which always reads:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
```

has been replaced by:

```
 * Restarting with stat
```

I don't think I've done anything different, in fact, I started by cloning a starter-kit project that I have used many times, which itself, does not display this behavior.  I also notice that this project consumes about 15% CPU steadily, whereas my other project are barely a blip.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Check your version of Werkzeug.  Version 0.10 was just released and numerous changes went into the reloader.  One change is that a default polling reloader is used; the old pyinotify reloader was apparently inaccurate.  If you want more efficient polling, install the [`watchdog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) package.  You can see the code related to this [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/4e2c6746e565eaba7b3bd7489337580b62db610b/werkzeug/_reloader.py#L246-L251).

When Werkzeug can't find watchdog, it uses the `stat` reloader, otherwise it uses whatever reloader watchdog uses, which can vary by platform.  This message is just so you know which one is in use.

---

Watchdog may not be compatible with gevent. If you're using gevent and having issues with the reloader when using Watchdog, check [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/306).

Answer (score 69):

Use `run(use_reloader=False)` to disable the reloader.

It gave me some problems where it wasn't able to find my server file when it restarted. This did the trick. It executed just once and everything worked. Quite odd.

Comment: In the OP I _wanted_ the reloader to be running - I just didn't want it to be hogging my cpu.

Answer (score 25):

If you run with `app.run(debug=True)`, it will run the reloader as part of debug mode. If you don't want to use debug mode, pass `debug=False` or don't pass it at all.

Answer (score 0):

my filename was __main__.py and I exported it as such: export FLASK_APP=__main__.py
Upon changing the name to app.py and reexporting it, it worked.