# flask dropbox causing error: ImportError: No module named _winreg

Tags: python, flask, dropbox, dropbox-api

So whenever I import dropbox into my Flask project, I get this error.

For example, even in the sample project,
https://github.com/WoLpH/dropbox/blob/master/example/flask_app/simple_dropbox_app.py

I suspect that the error is caused by this line:

```
12 DEBUG = True
```

But I don't know why. This is the error I get from running the sample project with no modification.

```
/Downloads/dropbox-master/example/flask_app$ python simple_dropbox_app.py 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple_dropbox_app.py", line 167, in <module>
    main()
  File "simple_dropbox_app.py", line 163, in main
    app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 622, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 269, in run_with_reloader
    reloader.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 159, in run
    for filename in chain(_iter_module_files(), self.extra_files):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 70, in _iter_module_files
    for package_path in getattr(module, '__path__', ()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 116, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 105, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 76, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

> **ImportError: No module named _winreg**

Comment: So what's trying to access the Windows registry on Linux?

Comment: I'm trying to use the dropbox API. I have no clue what it's doing. Does it not work on Linux? That would be odd that the dropbox API only works on Windows machines. I thought the problem was my code which is why I tried the sample project. It also doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have details, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258705/aws-ec2-winreg-not-found.

Comment: I ran pip install Werkzeug==0.9.6, is this fine?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today, looks like this is related to Werkzeug>=0.10. However Werkzeug==0.9 works as expected.

Comment: It's a bug in the `six` library. https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issue/87/six-tries-to-import-inappropriate-modules What version of `six` do you have? (Run `pip freeze`.) I had the same problem recently and upgraded `six` to `1.9.0` and it fixed my problem. (`pip install -U six`)

Answer (score 1):

Just `sudo pip install flask --upgrade`. The latest version fix this bug!