# Python - Importing paypalrestsdk causes ImportError: No module named _winreg

Tags: python, rest, ubuntu, paypal, flask

Any time I try to import paypalrestsdk in a python file, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runserver.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 622, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 269, in run_with_reloader
    reloader.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 159, in run
    for filename in chain(_iter_module_files(), self.extra_files):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 70, in _iter_module_files
    for package_path in getattr(module, '__path__', ()):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 116, in __getattr__
    _module = self._resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 105, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 76, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _winreg
```

I'm using Flask and the import was in the routes.py, but I got the same error when I put the import in the **init**.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the module watchdog or downgrade the werkzeug's version. There seems to be some issues with the latest werzeug's version as explained here [AWS ec2 winreg not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258705/aws-ec2-winreg-not-found)